# SQL Server Reporting Services - Send Reports from different email addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have two reports, Report A & Report B, that are emailed to their respective subscribers. 
At the moment they are both emailed from the same email address, say email@domain.com.
How do I send Report A from senderA@domain.com & Report B from senderB@domain.com?

Below is a section of the rsreportserver.config:

```
<Configuration>
<RSEmailDPConfiguration>
    <SMTPServer>smtp.server.com</SMTPServer>
    <SMTPServerPort>25</SMTPServerPort>
    <SMTPAccountName></SMTPAccountName>
    <SMTPConnectionTimeout>10000</SMTPConnectionTimeout>
    <SMTPServerPickupDirectory></SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
    <SMTPUseSSL>1</SMTPUseSSL>
    <SendUsing>2</SendUsing>
    <SMTPAuthenticate>0</SMTPAuthenticate>
        <From>email@domain.com</From>
    <EmbeddedRenderFormats>
        <RenderingExtension>MHTML</RenderingExtension>
    </EmbeddedRenderFormats>
    <PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
    </PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
    <ExcludedRenderFormats>
        <RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension>
        <RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension>
        <RenderingExtension>RGDI</RenderingExtension>
    </ExcludedRenderFormats>
    <SendEmailToUserAlias>True</SendEmailToUserAlias>
    <DefaultHostName>default.host.com</DefaultHostName>
    <PermittedHosts>
        <HostName>host1.co.za</HostName>
        <HostName>host2.co.za</HostName>
        <HostName>host3.co.za</HostName>
    </PermittedHosts>
</RSEmailDPConfiguration>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Reply-To option can be configured per subscription.